What is the standard reference medium in which positron ranges data are obtained in property tables, specifically for isotopes used in PET?
What is the standard reference medium in which positron ranges data are obtained in property tables, specifically for isotopes used in (Positron Emission Tomography (PET)?
I can't find any valuable information on the subject - only raw values without description.

Not sure if this will fully answer your question, but the following reference describes positron ranges (for the table in the article) as being in water.
Please see this reference for more details:
https://ejnmmiphys.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40658-016-0144-5/tables/1
